# Select pattern at the list sub-level

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I want to get a list from a parent list (containing sub-lists of unequal length) using `Cases` and a matching pattern. The parent list is

```
data = {{x,y,z,a},{a,x^m,y^n},{a,b^m}, {a,x,b,c}}
```

I want to pick the matching patterns `(x^_,y^_)` from the sub-lists and keep them in a similar list format.
Using `Cases` (at level spec 2), I could almost achieve that but unfortunately, it writes in a single list (instead of keeping the patterns in the same sub-list from where they belong). Eg,

```
Cases[data,Alternatives@@{x|x^_,y|y^_},2]
```

gives me

```
{x, y, x^m, y^n, x}
```

whereas, the output I want

```
{{x, y}, {x^m, y^n}, {}, {x}}
```

such that the final findings corresponding to the matched pattern result similar format (even if it is an empty sub-list).

Comment: Suppose you `Map[Cases[#,...yourpattern...]&,data]` That should use `Cases` on each of your sublists and return the results from each of those as a list and then all those lists will be returned in an enclosing list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just map the Cases expression over the list:

```
Cases[Alternatives[x | x^_ | y | y^_]] /@ data
```

Comment: `Alternatives` is redundant, so:   `Cases[x | x^_ | y | y^_] /@ data`

Comment: lol! I simplified the disjunction but then didn't discard the wrapper!

Answer (score 8):

`Pick` performs the sort of operation the OP seeks, but it can be rather tricky (to me).

```
Pick[
 data,
 data /. {(x | y)^_. -> True, Except[_List | List] -> False}]

(*  {{x, y}, {x^m, y^n}, {}, {x}}  *)
```

Note: It will pick all form at all levels.

To get everything down only to level 2:

```
level = 2;
data2 = {{x, y, z, a}, {a, x^m, y^n}, {a, b^m}, {a, x, b, c, {x^2}}};
Pick[data2,
 Replace[data2, {(x | y)^_. -> True}, level] /. 
  Except[True | List | _List] -> False]

(*  {{x, y}, {x^m, y^n}, {}, {x, {}}}  *)
```

Comment: Here's an example of its trickiness: `Pick[data, data, (x | y)^_.]` has a `{1}` instead of the `{}` in the output.

Comment: I like the improvement dot `.`  :)

Answer (score 7):

```
data = {{x,y,z,a},{a,x^m,y^n},{a,b^m}, {a,x,b,c}}

DeleteCases[data, Except[x | x^_ | y | y^_], {2}]
```

> `{{x, y}, {x^m, y^n}, {}, {x}}`

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {{x, y, z, a}, {a, x^m, y^n}, {a, b^m}, {a, x, b, c}};
```

Define pattern

```
p = x | x^_ | y | y^_;
```

Using `SequenceCases`

```
Catenate @ SequenceCases[#, {p}] & /@ data
```

> {{x, y}, {x^m, y^n}, {}, {x}}

Using `SequenceSplit`

```
Catenate @ SequenceSplit[#, {Except @ p}] & /@ data
```

> {{x, y}, {x^m, y^n}, {}, {x}}

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{x, y, z, a}, {a, x^m, y^n}, {a, b^m}, {a, x, b, c}};

data2 = {{x, y, z, a}, {a, x^m, y^n}, {a, b^m}, {a, x, b, c, {x^2}}};
```

---

Define pattern:

```
p = x | x^_ | y | y^_;
```

Using `SubsetReplace`:

```
f = Activate@Internal`CopyListStructure[#, 
    SubsetReplace[Flatten@#, {Except[p]} -> Inactive[Nothing]]] &;

f@data

(*{{x, y}, {x^m, y^n}, {}, {x}}*)

f@data2

(*{{x, y}, {x^m, y^n}, {}, {x, {x^2}}}*)
```